# Can't get multitouch work on cocos2d-x v3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, multi-touch

I'm using cocos2d-x v3.3rc0
I'm trying to handle multi touch, but I only receive only one touch.
It's behavior is similar with single touch, not multitouch. onTouchesBegan only called once when I touch more than 1 finger.

Hope someone can help me solve this out.

Here is my code to enable multi touch

**ControlLayer.h**

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

class ControlLayer : public cocos2d::Layer{


public:

    static ControlLayer* create();
    virtual bool init();

    void onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch*>& touches, cocos2d::Event *unused_event);
    void onTouchesMoved(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch*>& touches, cocos2d::Event *unused_event);
    void onTouchesEnded(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch*>& touches, cocos2d::Event *unused_event);

};
```

**ControlLayer.cpp**

```
bool ControlLayer::init(){

    if (!Layer::init()){
        return false;
    }

    auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
    touchListener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(ControlLayer::onTouchesBegan, this);
    touchListener->onTouchesMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(ControlLayer::onTouchesMoved, this);
    touchListener->onTouchesEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(ControlLayer::onTouchesEnded, this);

    Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);

    return true;
}

void ControlLayer::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event){
    CCLOG("onTouchesBegan[%lu]", touches.size());
}
void ControlLayer::onTouchesMoved(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event){
    CCLOG("onTouchesMoved[%lu]", touches.size());
}
void ControlLayer::onTouchesEnded(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event){

}
```

Comment: What does CCLOG("onTouchesBegan[%lu]", touches.size()); print in onTouchesBegan ?

Comment: The log is "onTouchesBegan[1]", and it called only once, the second finger will not effect.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable multitouch on each platform to support it natively.

Here's an example(iOS):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Init the CCEAGLView
CCEAGLView *eaglView = [CCEAGLView viewWithFrame: [window bounds]
                                 pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                 depthFormat: GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
                          preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                  sharegroup: nil
                               multiSampling: NO
                             numberOfSamples: 0];

[eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]; // <-----
```

Comment: The question is for cocos2d-x which uses c++ and your answer is for objective-c with cocos2d.

Comment: @whiteSkar My answer is for cocos2d-x. Each native AppDelegate will delegate each UIApplicationDelegate call to the shared(c++) delegate. Therefore, the principle of enabling the multitouch is valid. The example I gave was the iOS implementation. I can't possibly put each and every implementation in the answer.

Comment: I see. I thought your "example" was the "answer". If that is just an example, I want to remove the downvote I made. However, it says I cannot remove my downvote unless your post is edited. Can you edit your post so I can remove my downvote?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable multi touch in the iOS part of your project, which will be in Objective C even if the rest of the project is written in C++. Template projects have the line `[eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];` in the app controller (AppController.mm) ready for you to change NO to YES.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you need to enable it. As of Cocos2d-x 3.16, modify a single line of the `RootViewController.mm` generated by the `cocos new` commandline tool to enable multi-touch.

```
--- a/proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.mm
+++ b/proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.mm
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@
                                      numberOfSamples: 0 ];

     // Enable or disable multiple touches
-    [eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
+    [eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```